# Why is my function in javascript not altering my array?

Tags: javascript

Im trying to make a tictactoe game on javascript and my function (place();) wont edit my array. can you not make edits to an array in a function using javascript? ive tried using variables instead of an array and that didnt work either. where did i go wrong?

```js
var board = ["#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","X"];

//board[9] refers to whose turn it is

function move(){
    if(board[9] == "X"){
        return readLine("Make a move X").toLowerCase()
    } else if(board[9] == "O"){
        return readLine("Make a move O").toLowerCase()
    } else {
        console.log("invalid")
    }
}

function place(whoseTurn, move){
    switch(whoseTurn) {
        case whoseTurn == "X":
                if(move == "a1" && board[0] == "#"){
                    board[0] = "X";
                    board[9] = "O";
                }
                else if(move == "a2" && board[1] == "#"){
                    board[1] = "X";
                    board[9] = "O";
                }
                else if(move == "a3" && board[2] == "#"){
                    board[2] = "X";
                    board[9] = "O";
                }
                else if(move == "b1" && board[3] == "#"){
                    board[3] = "X";
                    board[9] = "O";
                }
                else if(move == "b2" && board[4] == "#"){
                    board[4] = "X";
                    board[9] = "O";
                }
                else if(move == "b3" && board[5] == "#"){
                    board[5] = "X";
                    board[9] = "O";
                }
                else if(move == "c1" && board[6] == "#"){
                    board[6] = "X";
                    board[9] = "O";
                }
                else if(move == "c2" && board[7] == "#"){
                    board[7] = "X";
                    board[9] = "O";
                }
                else if(move == "c3" && board[8] == "#"){
                    board[8] = "X";
                    board[9] = "O";
                }
                else{
                    console.log("error")
                }
            break;
        case whoseTurn == "O":
                if(move == "a1" && board[0] == "#"){
                    board[0] = "O";
                    board[9] = "X";
                }
                else if(move == "a2" && board[1] == "#"){
                    board[1] = "O";
                    board[9] = "X";
                }
                else if(move == "a3" && board[2] == "#"){
                    board[2] = "O";
                    board[9] = "X";
                }
                else if(move == "b1" && board[3] == "#"){
                    board[3] = "O";
                    board[9] = "X";
                }
                else if(move == "b2" && board[4] == "#"){
                    board[4] = "O";
                    board[9] = "X";
                }
                else if(move == "b3" && board[5] == "#"){
                    board[5] = "O";
                    board[9] = "X";
                }
                else if(move == "c1" && board[6] == "#"){
                    board[6] = "O";
                    board[9] = "X";
                }
                else if(move == "c2" && board[7] == "#"){
                    board[7] = "O";
                    board[9] = "X";
                }
                else if(move == "c3" && board[8] == "#"){
                    board[8] = "O";
                    board[9] = "X";
                }
                else{
                    console.log("error")
                }
            break;
    }
}
```

any advice helps! also please be patient with me im rather new.

Comment: Do you use `"use strict"`? When you do this, global variables are not put in the `window` object.

Comment: Please reduce this to a ***minimal*** [mre]. We don't need *all* these lines to understand something about global variables, do we?

Comment: Rather than try to solve this problem, you should stop using global variables. Put the board in an array, and pass that as an argument to all the functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are using `switch`, instead of a condition, you should put just a value in your `case`. Therefore, instead of `case whoseTurn == "X":` it should be just `case "X":`

If I make such a modification to the code, it works as expected and modifies the `board`.

Run the snippet below to see the updated board.

Please let me know if this helps.

```js
var board = ["#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","X"];

//board[9] refers to whose turn it is

function move(){
    if(board[9] == "X"){
        return readLine("Make a move X").toLowerCase()
    } else if(board[9] == "O"){
        return readLine("Make a move O").toLowerCase()
    } else {
        console.log("invalid")
    }
}

function place(whoseTurn, move){
    switch(whoseTurn) {
        case "X":
                if(move == "a1" && board[0] == "#"){
                    board[0] = "X";
                    board[9] = "O";
                }
                else if(move == "a2" && board[1] == "#"){
                    board[1] = "X";
                    board[9] = "O";
                }
                else if(move == "a3" && board[2] == "#"){
                    board[2] = "X";
                    board[9] = "O";
                }
                else if(move == "b1" && board[3] == "#"){
                    board[3] = "X";
                    board[9] = "O";
                }
                else if(move == "b2" && board[4] == "#"){
                    board[4] = "X";
                    board[9] = "O";
                }
                else if(move == "b3" && board[5] == "#"){
                    board[5] = "X";
                    board[9] = "O";
                }
                else if(move == "c1" && board[6] == "#"){
                    board[6] = "X";
                    board[9] = "O";
                }
                else if(move == "c2" && board[7] == "#"){
                    board[7] = "X";
                    board[9] = "O";
                }
                else if(move == "c3" && board[8] == "#"){
                    board[8] = "X";
                    board[9] = "O";
                }
                else{
                    console.log("error")
                }
            break;
        case "O":
                if(move == "a1" && board[0] == "#"){
                    board[0] = "O";
                    board[9] = "X";
                }
                else if(move == "a2" && board[1] == "#"){
                    board[1] = "O";
                    board[9] = "X";
                }
                else if(move == "a3" && board[2] == "#"){
                    board[2] = "O";
                    board[9] = "X";
                }
                else if(move == "b1" && board[3] == "#"){
                    board[3] = "O";
                    board[9] = "X";
                }
                else if(move == "b2" && board[4] == "#"){
                    board[4] = "O";
                    board[9] = "X";
                }
                else if(move == "b3" && board[5] == "#"){
                    board[5] = "O";
                    board[9] = "X";
                }
                else if(move == "c1" && board[6] == "#"){
                    board[6] = "O";
                    board[9] = "X";
                }
                else if(move == "c2" && board[7] == "#"){
                    board[7] = "O";
                    board[9] = "X";
                }
                else if(move == "c3" && board[8] == "#"){
                    board[8] = "O";
                    board[9] = "X";
                }
                else{
                    console.log("error")
                }
            break;
    }
}

place("X", "a1");
console.log(board);
```